# How to hidden selector is showing by click any different selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want create notify look like FaceBook, look [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Swon0.png) ,i was created, in my code, i'm using event `onClick`for `icon notify` then `addClass('open')` for . when `<ul class="notify-content dropdown-menu open">` is open, i want to click anywhere (note: different selector) in this window will `removeClass('open')`. how to do that?

**Here is my code:**

```
$('#layout-topbar-right .notify-warring').on('click', function() {
    var dom = $('layout-topbar-right .dropdown-menu');
    if ($(dom).hasClass('open')) {
        $(dom).removeClass('open');
    } else {
        $(dom).addClass('open');
    }
});
```

Comment: Post a part of your code which contains what you mentioned

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina [https://jsfiddle.net/huytuduy/ajwy024k/1/]

Comment: I meant you can post it here, so anyone can help you

Comment: sory, but i don't know comment with code, 
`$('#layout-topbar-right .notify-warring').on('click', function() {
  var dom = $('layout-topbar-right .dropdown-menu');
  if ($(dom).hasClass('open')) {
    $(dom).removeClass('open');
  } else {
    $(dom).addClass('open');
  }
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).parents('#layout-topbar-right').length) {
        $(dom).removeClass('open')
    }
});
```

When the user click on document then we check what element he clicked by using `e.target`.

If the clicked element is outside of parent `#layout-topbar-right`:

```
if (!$(e.target).parents('#layout-topbar-right').length)
```

You hide your `dom`

Here the complete code

```
var dom;
$('#layout-topbar-right .notify-warring').on('click', function() {
    dom = $('layout-topbar-right .dropdown-menu');
    if ($(dom).hasClass('open')) {
        $(dom).removeClass('open');
    } else {
        $(dom).addClass('open');
    }
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).parents('#layout-topbar-right').length) {
      $(dom).removeClass('open')
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$( document.body ).click(function() {
  // your codes
});
```

Or
    document.body.addEventListener('click', fn, true);